# How to copy a column and reduce the detail of the source data by repeating values several times

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column with very detailed data and I am trying to overlay it in a chart that has related data.

I need to reduce the detail of one of the columns as the chat is very noisy, however it needs to still match the timeline of the second column.

In the picture below, I have the noisy data on the left and the desired output on the right.

I want to create a formula that takes a value and repeats it 5 times before taking a new value, repeating it 5 times - and so on until there is no data left

[image]

I have tried to use `REDUCE` and `ArrayFormula` without success. Any idea how I could achieve this?

Comment: Why 1011 is repeated 6 times?

Comment: Do you want each unique values to repeat 5 times?

Comment: That was a mistake, haha - proof as to why doing things by hand is unreliable. It doesn't matter if the value is unique, just trying to reduce the level of detail

Answer (score 1):

*Here's one approach via `reduce` fx:*

```js
=let(Σ,tocol(,1),
     reduce(Σ,A1:index(A:A,match(,0/(A:A<>""))),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,if(mod(row(c),5)=1,wrapcols(c,5,c),Σ)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, amazing. How can you skip the header row? From `A2:A`?

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed that. I tried changing `A:A<>` to `A2:A<>`. Thanks!

Comment: try: `=let(Σ,tocol(,1),reduce(Σ,A2:index(A:A,match(,0/(A:A<>""))),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,if(mod(row(c),5)=2,wrapcols(c,5,c),Σ)))))`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

`=LET(d,A2:A,r,5,c,COUNTA(d),ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(TOCOL(MAP(FILTER(TOCOL(d,1),1=MOD(SEQUENCE(c),r)),LAMBDA(v,WRAPROWS(v,r,v)))),c,1))`

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach:

```
=arrayformula(array_constrain(tocol(query(A2:A,"where A is not null skipping 5",0)&wraprows(,5,)),counta(A2:A),1))
```